# how insert a array json into index at other const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how get called promise at api on items? how can change this to near .map()

```
async function componentDidMount() {

        const timestamp = Number(new Date())
        const hash = md5.create()
        hash.update(timestamp + PRIVATE_KEY + PUBLIC_KEY)

        try{
            var response = await fetch(`https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=${timestamp}&limit=10&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash.hex()}`)
            var responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log('resposta da API ',responseJson.data.results);
            var list = responseJson.data.results; // object for iteration
            return await list;
        }catch (err) {
            console.log('Erro:', err);
        }


}

const initState = {
    items: [
        {id:1,title:'Winter body', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:110,img:Item1},
        {id:2,title:'Adidas', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:80,img: Item2},
        {id:3,title:'Vans', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.",price:120,img: Item3},
        {id:4,title:'White', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:260,img:Item4},
        {id:5,title:'Cropped-sho', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:160,img: Item5},
        {id:6,title:'Blues', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.",price:90,img: Item6}
    ],
    addedItems:[],
    total: 0

}
```

Array initState.items near .map()
i need iterate this responseJson.data.results; to Items

```
let itemList = this.props.items.map(item=>{
            return( ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kB0a.png)

Comment: do you need to display a result of your request ?

Comment: I did it in the first page, but dont reusable.